# Angular doesnt add ng-leave on nested routes

Tags: angularjs, css

Im using angular 1.3 and im using ng animate to animate view change.
If i switch from `/route1` to `/route2` animation works just fine it animates `ng-enter` and `ng-leave`. But if I switch from `/route1` to `/route1/1` it animates `ng-enter` but it doesnt animate `ng-leave`(It only disappears without any animation).
My CSS looks like this

```
.ng-leave        {
  -webkit-animation:slideOutLeft 0.7s both cubic-bezier(0.610, 0.120, 0.395, 0.900);
  -moz-animation:slideOutLeft 0.7s both cubic-bezier(0.610, 0.120, 0.395, 0.900);
  animation:slideOutLeft 0.7s both cubic-bezier(0.610, 0.120, 0.395, 0.900);
}
.ng-enter       {
  -webkit-animation:slideInRight 0.7s both cubic-bezier(0.610, 0.120, 0.395, 0.900);
  -moz-animation:slideInRight 0.7s both cubic-bezier(0.610, 0.120, 0.395, 0.900);
  animation:slideInRight 0.7s both cubic-bezier(0.610, 0.120, 0.395, 0.900);
}

@keyframes slideInRight {
  from  { transform:translateX(100%); }
  to        { transform: translateX(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideInRight {
  from  { -moz-transform:translateX(100%); }
  to        { -moz-transform: translateX(0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInRight {
  from  { -webkit-transform:translateX(100%); }
  to        { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
}
@keyframes slideOutLeft {
  to        { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideOutLeft {
  to        { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideOutLeft {
  to        { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

Comment: Does it relate to this issue? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6974

Comment: It is kinda... I dont use any further classes to describe animation because I only have 1 animation for all my ng-view transitions. I also noticed that if I go forward with the browser arrow it animates view change as expected

Comment: Can you open up an issue on github then? Make sure to reference @matsko in the description so I can have a look at fixing it.

Comment: I submitted... tnx for your response